# Bootstrap3 remote modal with javascript in remote?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap3, I have a button:

```
    <a id="addSiteButton" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSiteModal" data-remote="/add_site" title="Add site" class='btn btn-primary'>Add Site</a>
```

and a modal code on the same page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addSiteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addSiteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Now this page fetches a modal from /add_site which looks like this

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.input-tooltips').tooltip({});
    });
</script>

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

           <a href="#"><span data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="tooltip here" class="input-tooltips glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> test</a>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the tooltip does not work when I hover on it.

However, if I directly go to /add_site from browser a modal is there and tooltip works.

So, how can I get a tooltip (and other js) to work when a model opens at /index

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The modal remote call fetch the page with jQuery's get() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Only the data will be transfered and displayed.

Add your data after the data is fetched and load:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $('.input-tooltips').tooltip({});
});
```

Add this in the document ready of your root document.